# In the top five, I'm odd

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, poetry

When I am done, I'm served.
When you are me, be proud.
In the top five, I'm odd.
I'm one of the unlucky ones, or royally envied.

What am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My answer:

> Ace

Explanation:

When I am done, I'm served.

> In tennis, an ace is a kind of serve.

When you are me, be proud.

> By definition, an ace is someone who excels at a particular activity. You can be proud!

In the top five, I'm odd.

> The word ace contains 3 of the first 5 letters of the alphabet - the odd ones.

I'm one of the unlucky ones...

> Ace can represent "one" in a deck of cards. Each suit has 13 ranks, and 13 is commonly known as an unlucky number.

...or royally envied.

> Ace can also represent the highest card, i.e. higher than the "royal" cards: King and Queen.

Comment: You have the word. The third line is not quite what I was going for. It is to do with letters. The fourth line is pretty much right, but you could elaborate on that a little more?

Comment: @rybo111 Is it correct now?

Comment: Third line is now spot on. For the last line, "**one** of the **unlucky** ones" has two important words. Also, "royally envied" is specifically about being greater than two things.

Comment: Obviously he knows it is higher than K and Q just said it in different words.

Comment: @rybo111 Fixed it!

Comment: I have added some minor changes and clarified the "unlucky" part. Good job with the answer, and welcome!

Comment: @rybo111 Thanks for the edits! It is clearer now.